# My table view cell data is changing while scrolling ,why?

Tags: ios

Anyone tell me why all times data changed? And what is  the solution?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

   if(cell==nil)
    {
       NSArray *friendDetailObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OrderNowCell" owner:self options:nil];

       NSLog(@"%@", friendDetailObjects);

       //  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cell];
       //  cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
       cell = [friendDetailObjects objectAtIndex:0];

      cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
...
```

Comment: Where is the code of set data in the `UITableIViewCell`?

Comment: `cell = [friendDetailObjects objectAtIndex:0];` alarm bells are ringing at the sight of this. What is it doing? Also, why are you using such old code style and syntax?

Comment: Ah, I see now. You are doing this entirely the wrong way. Have a look at how to use a nib to create a UITableViewCell.

Comment: I have not got the solution yet guys. Plz help me out

Answer (score 0):

OK, you are going about this in entirely the wrong way.

First you should register the nib with the tableview...

```
[self.tableview registerNib:[UINib nibWithName:@"OrderNowCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"OrderNowCell:];
```

Do this in `viewDidLoad` or something.

Then in cell for row...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // this may need to be your custom cell subclass...
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"OrderNowCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    // add other details to cell here.

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @fogmeister

Answer (score -1):

Write the line of code which set the data of cell outside the `if` condition. Something like below line of code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];




  cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

NSArray *friendDetailObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OrderNowCell" owner:self options:nil];

   NSLog(@"%@", friendDetailObjects);

   //  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cell];
   //  cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
   cell = [friendDetailObjects objectAtIndex:0];
```

...

Comment: LOL, really. This fixes your problem? I'd love for you to explain how. Haha. Also, there is no dequeueing going on here. If you are creating the cell that way (arguably the wrong way) then you are bypassing the dequeueing system in the table entirely. Performance will be under par and memory usage will sky rocket. It also makes the entirely first line of this method redundant. Oh well.

Comment: Actually the data is coming but its fluctuation while scrolling

Comment: @PRADIPKUMAR yes, so why did you accept this answer? It is just as wrong as the code in your question. Take a look at my answer.